# How to disassemble, modify and then reassemble a Linux executable?

Tags: linux, x86, disassembly, objdump

Is there anyway this can be done? I've used objdump but that doesn't produce assembly output that will be accepted by any assembler that I know of. I'd like to be able to change instructions within an executable and then test it afterwards.

Comment: @James Anderson Not necessarily true of all executables you ever encounter.

Comment: @JamesAnderson, I'm currently looking at an "open-source" code that was written for a commercial compiler and doesn't compile cleanly under gcc.

Comment: On other sites: http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/185/how-do-i-add-functionality-to-an-existing-binary-executable | http://askubuntu.com/questions/617441/how-can-edit-a-executable-file-linux

Comment: You can use radare2, by opening it in write mode with the -w flag. https://github.com/radare/radare2/blob/master/doc/intro.md

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I don't think there is any reliable way to do this. Machine code formats are very complicated, more complicated than assembly files. It isn't really possible to take a compiled binary (say, in ELF format) and produce a source assembly program which will compile to the same (or similar-enough) binary. To gain an understanding of the differences, compare the output of GCC compiling direct to assembler (`gcc -S`) versus the output of objdump on the executable (`objdump -D`).

There are two major complications I can think of. Firstly, the machine code itself is not a 1-to-1 correspondence with assembly code, because of things like pointer offsets.

For example, consider the C code to Hello world:

```
int main()
{
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles to the x86 assembly code:

```
.LC0:
    .string "hello"
    .text
<snip>
    movl    $.LC0, %eax
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    call    printf
```

Where .LCO is a named constant, and printf is a symbol in a shared library symbol table. Compare to the output of objdump:

```
80483cd:       b8 b0 84 04 08          mov    $0x80484b0,%eax
80483d2:       89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
80483d5:       e8 1a ff ff ff          call   80482f4 <printf@plt>
```

Firstly, the constant .LC0 is now just some random offset in memory somewhere -- it would be difficult to create an assembly source file which contains this constant in the correct place, since the assembler and linker are free to choose locations for these constants.

Secondly, I'm not entirely sure about this (and it depends on things like position independent code), but I believe the reference to printf is not actually encoded at the pointer address in that code there at all, but the ELF headers contain a lookup table which dynamically replaces its address at runtime. Therefore, the disassembled code doesn't quite correspond to the source assembly code.

In summary, source assembly has *symbols* while compiled machine code has *addresses* which are difficult to reverse.

The second major complication is that an assembly source file can't contain all of the information that was present in the original ELF file headers, like which libraries to dynamically link against, and other metadata placed there by the original compiler. It would be difficult to reconstruct this.

Like I said, it's possible that a special tool can manipulate all of this information, but it is unlikely that one can simply produce assembly code which can be reassembled back to the executable.

If you are interested in modifying just a small section of the executable, I recommend a much more subtle approach than recompiling the whole application. Use objdump to get the assembly code for the function(s) you are interested in. Convert it to "source assembly syntax" by hand (and here, I wish there was a tool that actually produced disassembly in the same syntax as the input), and modify it as you wish. When you are done, recompile just those function(s) and use objdump to figure out the machine code for your modified program. Then, use a hex editor to manually paste the new machine code over the top of the corresponding part of the original program, taking care that your new code is precisely the same number of bytes as the old code (or all the offsets would be wrong). If the new code is shorter, you can pad it out using NOP instructions. If it is longer, you may be in trouble, and might have to create new functions and call them instead.

Comment: Unless symbols are intentionally stripped many are retained. Try nm /bin/ls.

Comment: I think you're overstating some difficulties for code to find its constants.  The main problem is that no asm syntax can uniquely represent the different-length encodings for the same instruction.  Agner Fog's [`objconv` disassembler](http://agner.org/optimize/) will disassemble into NASM, YASM, MASM, or GNU as syntax.  That output can be assembled back into a similar binary, but any assumptions the code made about alignment / offsets might have changed.  e.g. the PLT (procedure linking table) needs to use the `jmp rel32` encoding so the right offset can be filled at run-time.

Comment: Update: GAS has prefixes that can request an explicit `disp32` even if the instruction doesn't need it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47673177/where-are-gnu-assembler-instruction-suffixes-like-s-in-x86-mov-s-documented.  Also, NASM can usually use `mov eax, [rdi + strict dword 0]` to force a disp32.  The problem is that disassemblers don't put in these overrides when disassembling longer-than-needed instructions.

Comment: Peter Cordes, of course an asm syntax can uniquely represent different encodings for the "same" instruction, different instructions with the same result. I've designed such a syntax, with the purpose of reverse engineering. See my answer

Comment: @Peter Cordes Regards missing overwrites, it just means that disassembler is not fit, not that there may not exist one. See also my answer. If you want a tool that has a magical knowledge of the particulars of an executable that is clearly impossible. If a tools has a scripting possibility to extract names for the executable (even of they are Huffman encoded, as is the case of one of my examples), and is precise in disciminating between all possible expression of the same function, then the sky is the limit. Groetjes Albert

Comment: Here you can find an example of modifying just a small section of the executable as discussed in the response: https://gist.github.com/simonemainardi/e63c03d6cefe65d0e2541a67e82955f9

Answer (score 27):

I do this with `hexdump` and a text editor. You have to be *really* comfortable with the machine code and the file format storing it, and flexible with what counts as "disassemble, modify, and then reassemble".

If you can get away with making just "spot changes" (rewriting bytes, but not adding nor removing bytes), it'll be easy (relatively speaking).

You *really* don't want to displace any existing instructions, because then you'd have to manually adjust any affected absolute address or relative offset within the machine code for jumps/branches/loads/stores relative to the program counter, both in hardcoded immediate values that can be clearly seen in the disassembly, *and* ones that are dynamically computed and can only be modified by changing instructions that change the address or offset in a register before it is used.

You should always be able to get away with not removing bytes. Adding bytes might be necessary for more complex modifications, and gets a lot harder.

#### Step 0 (preparation)

After you've *actually* disassembled the file properly with `objdump -D` or whatever you normally use first to actually understand it and find the spots you need to change, you'll need to take note of the following things to help you locate the correct bytes to modify:

1. The "address" (offset from the start of the file) of the bytes you need to change.
2. The raw value of those bytes as they currently are (the `--show-raw-insn` option to `objdump` is really helpful here).

You'll also need to check if `hexdump -R` works on your system. If not, then for the rest of these steps, use the `xxd` command or similar instead of `hexdump` in all of the steps below (consult the documentation for whatever tool you use, I only explain `hexdump` for now in this answer because that is the one I am familiar with).

#### Step 1

Dump the raw hexadecimal representation of the binary file with `hexdump -Cv`.

#### Step 2

Open the `hexdump`ed file and find the bytes at the address you're looking to change.

Quick crash course in `hexdump -Cv` output:

1. The left-most column is the addresses of the bytes (relative to the start of the binary file itself, just like `objdump` provides).
2. The right-most column (surrounded by `|` characters) is just "human readable" representation of the bytes - the ASCII character matching each byte is written there, with a `.` standing in for all bytes which don't map to an ASCII printable character.
3. The important stuff is in between - each byte as two hex digits separated by spaces, 16 bytes per line.

Beware: Unlike `objdump -D`, which gives you the address of each instruction and shows the raw hex of the instruction based on how it's documented as being encoded, `hexdump -Cv` dumps each byte exactly in the order it appears in the file. This can be a little confusing at first on machines where the instruction bytes are in opposite order due to endianness differences, which can also be disorienting when you're expecting a specific byte at a specific address.

#### Step 3

Modify the bytes that need to change - you obviously need to figure out the raw machine instruction encoding (not the assembly mnemonics) and manually write in the correct bytes.

Note: You **don't** need to change the human-readable representation in the right-most column. `hexdump` will ignore it when you "un-dump" it.

#### Step 4

"Un-dump" the modified hexdump file using `hexdump -R`.

#### Step 5 (sanity check)

`objdump` your newly un`hexdump`ed file and verify that the disassembly that you changed looks correct. `diff` it against the `objdump` of the original.

Seriously, don't skip this step. I make a mistake more often than not when manually editing the machine code and this is how I catch most of them.

#### Example

Here's a real-life worked example from when I modified an ARMv8 (little endian) binary recently. (I know, the question is tagged `x86`, but I don't have an x86 example handy, and the fundamental principles are the same, just the instructions are different.)

In my situation I needed to disable a specific "you shouldn't be doing this" hand-holding check: in my example binary, in `objdump --show-raw-insn -d` output the line I cared about looked like this (one instruction before and after given for context):

```
     f40:   aa1503e3    mov x3, x21
     f44:   97fffeeb    bl  af0 <error@plt>
     f48:   f94013f7    ldr x23, [sp, #32]
```

As you can see, our program is "helpfully" exiting by jumping into an `error` function (which terminates the program). Unacceptable. So we're going to turn that instruction into a no-op. So we're looking for the bytes `0x97fffeeb` at the address/file-offset `0xf44`.

Here is the `hexdump -Cv` line containing that offset.

```
00000f40  e3 03 15 aa eb fe ff 97  f7 13 40 f9 e8 02 40 39  |..........@...@9|
```

Notice how the relevant bytes are actually flipped (little endian encoding in the architecture applies to machine instructions like to anything else) and how this slightly unintuitively relates to what byte is at what byte offset:

```
00000f40  -- -- -- -- eb fe ff 97  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  |..........@...@9|
                      ^
                      This is offset f44, holding the least significant byte
                      So the *instruction as a whole* is at the expected offset,
                      just the bytes are flipped around. Of course, whether the
                      order matches or not will vary with the architecture.
```

Anyway, I know from looking at other disassembly that `0xd503201f` disassembles to `nop` so that seems like a good candidate for my no-op instruction. I modified the line in the `hexdump`ed file accordingly:

```
00000f40  e3 03 15 aa 1f 20 03 d5  f7 13 40 f9 e8 02 40 39  |..........@...@9|
```

Converted back into binary with `hexdump -R`, disassembled the new binary with `objdump --show-raw-insn -d` and verified that the change was correct:

```
     f40:   aa1503e3    mov x3, x21
     f44:   d503201f    nop
     f48:   f94013f7    ldr x23, [sp, #32]
```

Then I ran the binary and got the behavior I wanted - the relevant check no longer caused the program to abort.

Machine code modification successful.

## !!! Warning !!!

Or was I successful? Did you spot what I missed in this example?

I am sure you did - since you're asking about how to manually modify the machine code of a program, you presumably know what you're doing. But for the benefit of any readers who might be reading to learn, I'll elaborate:

I only changed the **last** instruction in the error-case branch! The jump into the function that exits the program. But as you can see, register `x3` was being modified by the `mov` just above! In fact, a total of *four (4)* registers were modified as part of the preamble to call `error`, and one register was. Here's the full machine code for that branch, starting from the conditional jump over the `if` block and ending where the jump goes to if the conditional `if` isn't taken:

```
     f2c:   350000e8    cbnz    w8, f48
     f30:   b0000002    adrp    x2, 1000
     f34:   91128442    add x2, x2, #0x4a1
     f38:   320003e0    orr w0, wzr, #0x1
     f3c:   2a1f03e1    mov w1, wzr
     f40:   aa1503e3    mov x3, x21
     f44:   97fffeeb    bl  af0 <error@plt>
     f48:   f94013f7    ldr x23, [sp, #32]
```

All of the code after the branch was generated by the compiler on the assumption that the program state was *as it was before the conditional jump*! But by just making the final jump to the `error` function code a no-op, I created a code path where we reach that code *with inconsistent/incorrect program state*!

In my case, this actually *seemed to* not cause any problems. So I got lucky. *Very* lucky: only after I already ran my modified binary (which, incidentally, was a *security-critical binary*: it had the capability to `setuid`, `setgid`, and change *SELinux context*!) did I realize that I forgot to actually trace the code paths of whether those register changes effected the code paths that came later!

That could've been catastrophic - any one of those registers might've been used in later code with the assumption that it contained a previous value that now got overwritten! And I'm the kind of person that people know for meticulous careful thought about code and as a pedant and stickler for always being conscientious of computer security.

What if I was calling a function where the arguments spilled from the registers onto the stack (as is very common on, for example, x86)? What if there was actually multiple conditional instructions in the instruction set that preceded the conditional jump (as is common on, for example, older ARM versions)? I would've been in an even more recklessly inconsistent state after having done that simplest-seeming change!

**So this my cautionary reminder:** Manually twiddling with binaries is literally *stripping away **every** safety* between you and what the machine and operating system will permit. Literally *all* the advances that we have made in our tools to automatically catch mistakes our programs, *gone*.

So how do we fix this more properly? Read on.

#### Removing Code

To *effectively*/*logically* "remove" more than one instruction, you can replace the first instruction you want to "delete" with an unconditional jump to the first instruction at the end of the "deleted" instructions. For this ARMv8 binary, that looked like this:

```
     f2c:   14000007    b   f48
     f30:   b0000002    adrp    x2, 1000
     f34:   91128442    add x2, x2, #0x4a1
     f38:   320003e0    orr w0, wzr, #0x1
     f3c:   2a1f03e1    mov w1, wzr
     f40:   aa1503e3    mov x3, x21
     f44:   97fffeeb    bl  af0 <error@plt>
     f48:   f94013f7    ldr x23, [sp, #32]
```

Basically, you "kill" the code (turn it into "dead code"). Sidenote: You can do something similar with literal strings embedded in the binary: so long as you want to replace it with a smaller string, you can almost always get away with overwriting the string (including the terminating null byte if it's a "C-string") and if necessary overwriting the hard-coded size of the string in the machine code that uses it.

You can also replace all unwanted instructions with no-ops. In other words, we can turn the unwanted code into what's called a "no-op sled":

```
     f2c:   d503201f    nop
     f30:   d503201f    nop
     f34:   d503201f    nop
     f38:   d503201f    nop
     f3c:   d503201f    nop
     f40:   d503201f    nop
     f44:   d503201f    nop
     f48:   f94013f7    ldr x23, [sp, #32]
```

I would expect that that's just wasting CPU cycles relative to jumping over them, *but* it is *simpler* and thus *safer against mistakes*, because you don't have to manually figure out how to encode the jump instruction including figuring out the offset/address to use in it - you don't have to *think as much* for a no-op sled.

To be clear, error is easy: I messed up *two (2)* times when manually encoding that unconditional branch instruction. And it's not always our fault: the first time was because the documentation I had was outdated/wrong and said one bit was ignored in the encoding, when it actually wasn't, so I set it to zero on my first try.

#### Adding Code

You *could* theoretically use this technique to *add* machine instructions too, but it's more complex, and I've never had to do it, so I don't have a worked example at this time.

From a machine code perspective it's sorta easy: pick one instruction at the spot you want to add code, and convert it into a jump instruction to the new code that you need add (don't forget to add the instruction(s) you thus replaced into the new code, unless you didn't need that for your added logic, and to jump back to the instruction you want to come back to at the end of the addition). Basically, you're "splicing" the new code in.

But you have to find a spot to actually put that new code, and this is the hard part.

If you're *really* lucky, you can just append the new machine code at the end of the file, and it'll "just work": the new code will get loaded along with the rest into the same expected machine instructions, into your address space space that falls into a memory page properly marked executable.

In my experience `hexdump -R` ignores not just the right-most column but the left-most column too - so you could literally just put zero addresses for all manually added lines and it'll work out.

If you're less lucky, after adding the code you'll have to actually adjust some header values within the same file: if the loader for your operating system expects the binary to contain metadata describing the size of the executable section (for historical reasons often called the "text" section) you'll have to find and adjust that. In the old days binaries were just raw machine code - nowadays the machine code is wrapped in a bunch of metadata (for example ELF on Linux and some others).

If you're still a little lucky, you might have some "dead" spot in the file which does get properly loaded up as part of the binary at the same relative offsets as the rest of the code that's already in the file (and that dead spot can fit your code and is properly aligned if your CPU requires word-alignment for CPU instructions). Then you can overwrite it.

If you're really unlucky you can't just append code and there is no dead space you can fill with your machine code. At that point, you basically have to be intimately familiar with the executable format and hope that you can figure out something within those constraints that is humanly feasible to pull off manually within a reasonable amount fo time and with a reasonable chance of not messing it up.

Comment: `hexdump` does'nt recognize `-R`. Instead we can use `xxd -r` for reverse hex dumping, but **beware** that `objdump` does'nt recognize the reverse hex-dumped binary file.

Comment: @Abhishek Mine does. I see the problem - I only do this trick on my very minimal systems, which have the `hexdump` from BusyBox, which was compiled with `FEATURE_HEXDUMP_REVERSE`. I've never tried `xxd -r` because that is not available on the systems I do this kind of work on. (Either way, if `objdump` does not recognize the resulting binary, I would suspect that the binary is wrong, and something went wrong.)

Comment: @Abhishek Thanks, I've gone ahead and added a little extra hint in the preparation (step 0) section about checking if `hexdump -R` works, and if not then using an alternative like `xxd` instead of `hexdump` for all of the commands.

Comment: X0, X1, X2, X3 are caller-saved/volatile registers, so the compiler cannot assume *anything* about those registers after the call to `error` anyway (assuming `error` does not return a value in X0, of course). If the compiler needed to save the contents of X0, X1, etc. it'd have emitted code to load/restore those registers from the stack and/or used callee-saved registers. So in your specific example, patching those register moves is unnecessary.

Comment: @léo-lam probably, but that's a risky assumption. What if that specific machine code just wasn't following the ABI calling convention you're thinking of? Many compilers have a way to change the calling convention for specific functions, or a way to inline raw machine code which is free to violate it. Optimizations *can* become free to change *anything* about how registers are used *if* it is known that both the function *and all of its callers* are being optimized to match, which is possible for a leaf function in a command-line program like this.

Comment: @mtraceur that's a fair point. In my experience looking at optimised C++ AArch64 code (mostly from Clang) and doing matching decompilation, functions that don't follow the standard calling convention are very rare though (at least in applications; kernels are a different story, of course) – so I think it's still worth mentioning that you can make your life easier in many cases if you know the platform ABI and know that it is being followed (and most of the time, it is, especially if the call goes through the PLT as in your example – that pretty much rules out weird optimisations).

Comment: @léo-lam I agree, and after seeing your first comment I did form some intent to mention calling conventions. However, now we come to the bigger teachable moment: the machine code right after the call to `error@plt` *had every right to ignore the effects of `error` on caller-saved registers*. Because the call to `error` was the last thing *inside an `if` block*, with a compile-time constant nonzero error code, which means that branch is well-defined to never return on the Linux system this was targeting, and the compiler was within its rights to know this and use that knowledge.

Comment: Basically, this isn't obvious from the snippet of machine code I included (unless you notice where the conditional branch instruction jumps and the `orr w0, wzr, 0x1`, and suspect that `error` is the `error(3)` function standardized in POSIX and so on), but that `error` call never returns, the compiler is fully justified in knowing that it never returns (in fact the corresponding C source could even contain something to tell the compiler that, such as a this-code-is-unreachable marker understood by the compiler, between the `error` call and the `}` that closes the `if`).

Comment: Even I didn't notice this at first! @léo-lam Because I didn't quite have time to think it through, to load up all possibilities in my mind again, and so I thought "yep, that *does* sound right about the calling convention, and the optimizations I can think of were probably not happening in this case, so yeah, I probably can conclude those register writes in the call preamble must be safe to execute in this case". But we were subtly wrong, and at least in my case that was definitely because I allowed myself to think with the calling convention without the right caveats built into that thinking.

Comment: So I *will* edit this answer to mention calling conventions, and how knowing them and letting them shape our expectations can save some work, but I want to first carefully figure how I can work it into the answer while still drawing attention to risks like this.

Answer (score 9):

@mgiuca has correctly addressed this answer from a technical point of view. In fact, disassemblying an executable program into an easy-to-recompile assembly source is not an easy task.

To add some bits to the discussion, there are a couple of techniques/tools which could be interesting to explore, although they are technically complex.

1. **Static/Dynamic instrumentation**. This technique entails analyzing the executable format, insert/delete/replace specific assembly instructions for a given purpose, fix all references to variables/functions in the executable, and the emit a new modified executable. Some tools which I know of are: [PIN](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/pin-a-dynamic-binary-instrumentation-tool), [Hijacker](https://github.com/HPDCS/hijacker), [PEBIL](https://github.com/mlaurenzano/PEBIL), [DynamoRIO](http://www.dynamorio.org/). Consider that configuring such tools to a purpose different from what they were designed for could be tricky, and requires understanding of both executable formats and instruction sets.
2. **Full executable decompilation**. This technique tries to reconstruct a full assembly source from an executable. You might want to give a glance to the [Online Disassembler](https://www.onlinedisassembler.com/odaweb/), which tries to do the job. You lose anyhow information about different source modules and possibly functions/variable names.
3. **Retargetable decompilation**. This technique tries to extract more information from the executable, looking at *compiler fingerprints* (i.e., patterns of code generated by known compilers) and other deterministic stuff. The main goal is to reconstruct higher-level source code, like C source, from an executable. This is sometimes able to regain information about functions/variables names. Consider that compiling sources with `-g` often offers better results. You might want to give the [Retargetable Decompiler](https://retdec.com/) a try.

Most of this comes from vulnerbility assessment and execution analysis research fields. They are complex techniques and often the tools cannot be used immediately out of the box. Nevertheless, they provide invaluable help when trying to reverse engineer some software.

Answer (score 7):

For changing code inside of an binary assembly, there are generally 3 ways to do it.

- If it is just some trivial thing like a constant, then you just change the location with a hex editor. Assuming you can find it to begin with.
- If you need to alter code, then utilize the LD_PRELOAD to overwrite some function in your program. That doesn't work if the function is not in the function tables though.
- Hack the code at the function you want to fix to be a direct jump to a function you load via LD_PRELOAD and then jump back to the same location (This is a combi of the above two)

Ofcourse only the 2nd one will work, if the assembly does any kind of self-integrity-check.

Edit: If it isn't obvious then playing around with binary assemblies is VERY high-level developer stuff, and you will have a hard time asking about it here, unless it is really specific things you ask.

Answer (score 2):

**miasm**

https://github.com/cea-sec/miasm

This appears to be the most promising concrete solution. According to the project description, the library can:

> - Opening / modifying / generating PE / ELF 32 / 64 LE / BE using Elfesteem
> - Assembling / Disassembling X86 / ARM / MIPS / SH4 / MSP430

So it should basically:

- parse the ELF into an internal representation (disassembly)
- modify what you want
- generate a new ELF (assembly)

I don't think it generates a textual disassembly representation, you will likely have to walk through Python data structures.

TODO find a minimal example of how to do all of that using the library. A good starting point seems to be [example/disasm/full.py](https://github.com/cea-sec/miasm/blob/52cec00d2b3162b8c622d7a1a1ec9b6752bfc614/example/disasm/full.py), which parses a given ELF file. The key top-level structurei is `Container`, which reads the ELF file with `Container.from_stream`. TODO how to reassemble it afterwards? This article seems to do it: http://www.miasm.re/blog/2016/03/24/re150_rebuild.html

This question asks if there are any other such libraries: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1843/what-are-the-available-libraries-to-statically-modify-elf-executables

Related questions:

- https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/185/how-do-i-add-functionality-to-an-existing-binary-executable
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/617441/how-can-edit-a-executable-file-linux

**I think this problem is not automatable**

I think the general problem is not fully automatable, and the general solution is basically equivalent to "how to reverse engineer" a binary.

In order to insert or remove bytes in a meaningful way, we would have to ensure that all possible jumps keep jumping to the same locations.

In formal terms, we need to extract the control flow graph of the binary.

However, with indirect branches for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indirect_branch , it is not easy to determine that graph, see also: [Indirect jump destination calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17298403/indirect-jump-destination-calculation)

Answer (score 2):

My "ci assembler disassembler" is the only system that I know is that is designed around the principle that whatever the disassembly is, it must reassemble to the byte for byte same binary.

https://github.com/albertvanderhorst/ciasdis

There are two examples given of elf-executables with their disassembly and reassembly. It was originally designed to be able to modify a booting system, consisting of code, interpreted code, data and graphic characters, with such niceties as a transition from real to protected mode. (It succeeded.) The examples demonstrate also the extraction of text from the executables, that is subsequently used for labels. The debian package is intended for Intel Pentium, but plug ins are available for Dec Alpha, 6809, 8086 etc.

The quality of the disassembly depends on how much effort you put into it. E.g., if you do not even supply the information that it is an elf file, the disassembly consist of single bytes, and the reassembly is trivial. In the examples I use a script that extracts labels, and makes for a truely usable reverse engineered program that is modifiable. You can insert or delete something and the automatically generated symbolic labels will get recalculated. With the tools provided labels are  generated for all places where jumps end, and then the labels are used for those jumps. That means that in most case you can insert an instruction and reassemble the modified source.

No assumption at all is made about the binary blob, but of course an Intel disassembly is of little use for a Dec Alpha binary.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you might be interested to do:

- binary instrumentation - changing existing code

If interested, check out: Pin, Valgrind (or projects doing this: NaCl - Google's Native Client, maybe QEmu.)

Answer (score 0):

You can run the executable under supervision of ptrace (in other words, a debugger like gdb) and in that way, control execution as you go, without modifying the actual file. Of course, requires the usual editing skills like finding where particular instructions you want to influence are in the executable.