# Error: expecting string instruction after `repz'

Tags: assembly, x86, elf, disassembly

So basically I am trying to re-use some asm code disassembled from `objdump` on 32 bit Linux, ELF binary.

In the disassembled file, I see this instruction:

```
8057a01:       f3 c3                   repz ret
```

and when I try to re-use `repz ret` in my asm code, I got this error:

```
 Error: expecting string instruction after `repz'
```

I tried to specify a `ret` type like this:

```
repz retq
```

but I still got the same error again..

Could anyone give me some help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disassembling, modifying and then reassembling a Linux executable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309771/disassembling-modifying-and-then-reassembling-a-linux-executable)

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I don't think so, please double-check what they are talking about and basically my question is why `repz ret` cannot be assembled

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your assembler probably wasn't prepared for that use of `repz`.

`repz` does not do anything per se when placed in front of a `ret` instruction, but it is used sometimes to prevent a jump directly to a `ret` instruction - for padding, essentially - because jumping directly to a `ret` has bad performance on certain CPU models.

You should be able to encode the instruction combination with a `db` sequence.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is simple, you just need to put the `repz` and the `ret` on two consecutive lines. Also note that this optimization is obsolete, AMD now recommends to use `ret 0` if your `ret` is a branch target (even for fall-through). In fact for even more recent AMD chips this whole optimization is not needed because the branch predictor works differently.