# Is it possible to convert .ipa compiled for iOS ARM to x86 which can run on emulator?

Tags: ios, ios8, ios-simulator, ipa, .app

Is there a way (tool or a process) to convert .ipa file downloaded from iTunes to something (.app?) which can run on ios simulator?

Comment: It is simply not possible. The compiled IPA file cannot be converted to an .app file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no easy way to do this.

[Here's a good answer that explains why it's not possible to disassemble an x86 binary and recompile it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4310317/2963024). Doing it from ARM to x86 would add one more huge obstacle to the problem.

I don't know why you would want to do this, but your best bet would probably be to search for the source code of the app you're trying to run in the simulator (or an alternative to the app, if it's not open source)

Comment: I would wipe the "right now" from the answer :-) Overall, decompiling to recompile machine is a so complex process that encompasses so many layers of computing architectures that I believe it will not be possible at all, at least in a fully automated way. Switching architectures adds an additional layer of problems related to ISA-diverse instructions which cannot be done automatically at all (e.g., RMW instructions across different architectures)