# Disassemble, modify, and reassemble executable

Tags: c, assembly, nasm, reverse-engineering, disassembly

How can I disassemble an executable on my mac using ndisasm and reassemble and link it using nasm and ld?
This is what I tried (I'm running MacOS X btw):

```
 *ndisasm a.out | cut -c 29- > main.asm*
```

this generated clean assembler code with all the processor instructions in main.asm

```
 *nasm -f macho main.asm*
```

this generated an object file main.o which I then tried to link

```
 *ld main.o*
```

... this is where I'm stuck. I don't know why it generates the following error:

ld: in section __TEXT,__text reloc 0: R_ABS reloc but no absolute symbol at target adress file 'main.o' for inferred architecture i386.

I also tried specifying the architecture (ld -arch x86_64 main.o) but that didn't work either.

**My goal is to disassemble any executable, modify it and then reassemble it again.**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Due to the fact that assembling and linking are performed by two different tools, getting the disassembly of a file is not enough to recreate the original binary. Furthermore, this also implies that the disassembler will pass over some binary properties that a "de-linker" should handle (do they exist?). For these reasons, people usually *patch* the binary file or edit it with a Mach-O editor to shift/grow/shrink sections around.

Comment: It will also certainly not work for **any** executable, some may have anti-tamper or just-too-complex code which will be broken by your modification and the reassembled executable will not work correctly (correctly = as before + your modification only). For example if you have `mov edi,0x123` in executable, how can you tell if it is loading memory address of data in `.text` `0x123`, or value `0x123`? In first case the value needs patching, if your modification was not in-place, in second case the value must be kept intact. There's no way to tell except deciphering the purpose of `edi` later.

Comment: Plus such tool is quite useless, it's much better to checkout original source from github/etc. and modify that (so don't expect there're many people trying to solve the same thing, many people are rather developing the SW).

Comment: It is recommended to ask questions about Reverse Engineering in [Reverse Engineering Stack Exchange](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com).

Comment: You can emit binary from an optionally modified disassembly in `Hopper` , I recommend checking it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no *reliable* way to do this with normal assembler syntax.  See  [How to disassemble, modify and then reassemble a Linux executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309771/how-to-disassemble-modify-and-then-reassemble-a-linux-executable).  Section info is typically not faithfully disassembled, so you'd need a special format designed for modify and reassembling + *relinking*.

Also, instruction-lengths are a problem when code only works when padded by using longer encodings.  (e.g. in a table of jump targets for a computed goto).  See [Where are GNU assembler instruction suffixes like ".s" in x86 "mov.s" documented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47673177/where-are-gnu-assembler-instruction-suffixes-like-s-in-x86-mov-s-documented), but note that disassemblers don't support disassembling into that format.

---

`ndisasm` doesn't understand object file formats, so it disassembles headers as machine code!

For this to have any hope of working, use a disassembler like [Agner Fog's `objconv`](http://agner.org/optimize/#objconv) which will output asm source (NASM, MASM, or GAS AT&T) which does assemble.  It might not actually work if any of the code depended on a specific longer-than-default encoding.

I'm not sure how faithful `objconv` is with respect to emitting `section .bss`, `section .rodata` and other directives like that to place data where it found it in the object file, but that's what you need.

---

Re: absolute relocations: make sure you put `DEFAULT REL` at the top of your file.  I forget if `objconv` does this by default.  x86-64 Mach-o only supports PC-relative relocations, so you have to create position-independent code (e.g. using RIP-relative addressing modes).

`ndisasm` doesn't read the symbol table, so all its operands use absolute addressing.  `objconv` makes up label names for jump targets and static data that doesn't appear in the symbol table.