# How do GNU assembler x86 instruction suffixes like ".s" in "mov.s" work?

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler, objdump, intel-syntax

GNU assembler appears to have some means of controlling the alternative forms of the opcode being emitted for some instructions. E.g.

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
mov   eax, ecx
mov.s eax, ecx
```

Processing the above code with `as test.s -o test.o && objdump -d test.o -M intel` gives the following disassembly:

```
0:   89 c8                   mov    eax,ecx
2:   8b c1                   mov    eax,ecx
```

We can see that `.s` suffix appears to switch `89` opcode to the `8b` version (and appropriately change the ModRM byte).

How does this syntax work in GAS?  I can't find any relevant documentation.

Comment: As worded, this is technically off topic because you're asking for a link to docs instead of directly asking for more details about how they work. (Which you could do in a way that would make a summary + link to docs a good answer).  Anyway, good question, it should stay open even though it bends the rules, IMO.

Comment: @Mogsdad: rephrased it to be on-topic, and voted to reopen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Binutils 2.29 the instruction suffixes are now [deprecated](https://sourceware.org/ml/binutils/2016-11/msg00166.html) in favor of pseudo-prefixes. You can find the older suffixes documented in the GNU Assembler (pre-2.29) [info pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Info_(Unix)). Earlier [`info as`](http://www.rowleydownload.co.uk/arm/documentation/gnu/as/i386_002dMnemonics.html) pages say this:

> 9.15.4.1 Instruction Naming
>
> [snip]
>
> Different encoding options can be specified via optional mnemonic suffix. **.s** suffix swaps 2 register operands in encoding when moving from one register to another. **.d8** or **.d32** suffix prefers 8bit or 32bit displacement in encoding.

Documenting the new pseudo prefixes, Binutils 2.29 (and later) [`info as`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dMnemonics.html) pages were revised to read:

> Different encoding options can be specified via pseudo prefixes:
>
> - **{disp8}** – prefer 8-bit displacement.
> - **{disp32}** – prefer 32-bit displacement.
> - **{load}** – prefer load-form instruction.
> - **{store}** – prefer store-form instruction.
> - **{vex2}** – prefer 2-byte VEX prefix for VEX instruction.
> - **{vex3}** – prefer 3-byte VEX prefix for VEX instruction.
> - **{evex}** – encode with EVEX prefix.

Comment: It would be cool if you could get `objdump` or other binutils tools to use these overrides when disassembling.  But I don't see anything relevant in the info page index.  Maybe a feature that a 3rd-party disassembler like Agner Fog's objconv could have, because it aims to make asm that can be re-assembled.