# GCC asm function, how to insert specific op code?

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, inline-assembly, opcode

I'm trying to use the asm function in C to insert redundant xor instructions:

```c
    int main (int argc, char** argv) {
        asm(".rept 100 ; xor %eax, %eax; .endr");
        return 0;
    }
```

which actually works but I want to know if there is a way to encode *specific* xor encodings. The assembler defaults to using opcode **0x31**, but I want to encode xor opcodes **0x81** and **0x35**.
(As seen here: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/xor)

I have tried replacing xor directly with the opcode:

`asm(".rept 100 ; \x35 %eax, %eax; .endr");`

But the assembler throws an invalid character error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As I interpret the table, the opcode depends on the parameters. `0x81` is used when the second parameter is an immediate value, `0x31` is used when it's a register.

Comment: That's what things like *imm16* and *r16* mean in the specifications of each instruction. You can't use arbitrary opcodes the way you want.

Comment: You can use a `.byte` directive to emit a specific byte.  There are also ways to select specific encodings in case there are multiple; refer to the GNU as manual for details.  But as @Barmer already said, opcodes `31` and `81` cannot be used in this case.

Comment: Ah man, that's disappointing to learn. However, it will save me time in the long run to know it won't possible this way.

Comment: @fuz: [How do GNU assembler x86 instruction suffixes like ".s" in "mov.s" work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47673177) details the old-style `.s` suffix to swap opcode, and the new-style `{load}` and `{store}` overrides, for selecting between `0x31` and `0x33` which are both valid choices, unlike any of the other opcodes.  You could add a REX prefix for xor rax,rax.  Or even a REX prefix with no bits set to not change the insn, assuming it's 64-bit mode.

Comment: Don't forget to declare the clobber of `eax` / `rax`!

Comment: This inline asm is unsafe; it writes EAX without telling the compiler about it.  You need `asm("xor %%eax,%%eax" ::: "eax")`.   There are other ways to zero a register, e.g. `sub reg,reg` or `mov reg,0`, but xor is the most efficient choice; sub isn't special-cased on some CPUs.

Comment: @ConnorPeper If you let me know what you are trying to achieve, perhaps I might be able to propose a better overall approach.